# Erro ao tentar colocar JCheckBox em uma coluna da JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou tentando acrescentar uma coluna em uma `DefaultTableModel`, mas parece está dando alguns problemas. Segue código!

```
JCheckBox jcheck;
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]{"Data", "Hora", "SAP", "BPCS", "Etiqueta", "Min", "Max", "MV", "Min", "Max", "T5", "Min", "Max", "TS2", "Min", "Max", "T90", "Min", "Max", "Densidade", "C-Chart", "Blooming","Aprovar"}) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }
};

jcheck = new JCheckBox();
TableColumn coluna_um = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(22);
coluna_um.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jcheck));
```

Alguém poderia da uma força?

Comment: Não é no tablemodel, ele serve para modelar dados, apenas isso. Para exibir combo na tabela, precisa criar um celleditor e um cellrenderer. Forneça um **[mcve]** do seu código para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Não vou manjar :(

Comment: Espera, no titulo você diz **ComboBox**, mas no código é **CheckBox**? Qual componente você está tentando adicionar afinal?

Comment: é check, estou ficando maluco já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JCheckBox` é um componente que pode ser considerado "booleano", ou seja, ou está marcado, ou não está. Como ele tem apenas dois estados, quando você define uma coluna com este tipo no `DefaultTableModel`, [o proprio renderer utiliza esse componente como representação de uma coluna booleana](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), e seu único trabalho é definir qual coluna deverá ser deste tipo. Veja no exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class JTableCheckboxTest extends JFrame{

    public void createAndShowGUI() {

        Object[][] rowData = {null, null, null};
        Object[] columnNames = { "Currency Column ", "Column Two",};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames){
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnIndex == 0 ? Boolean.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(model);       

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IllegalAccessException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new JTableCheckboxTest().createAndShowGUI());
    }
}
```

Repare que no método `getColumnClass()` eu faço uma verificação para saber se o índice da coluna é 0, quando for, a coluna será do tipo booleana, o que fará dela uma coluna de Checkboxes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um ponto do seu código que vale ressaltar é que, por padrão, todas as colunas de um `DefaultTableModel` são editáveis, logo, sobrescrever o método `isCellEditable()` para retornar true é redundante.

Comment: Nossa @Articuno, perfeito cara..

Comment: @Lucas16 é mais simples do que parece ne :p

Comment: Muito haha.. agora quero só ver como vou fazer para percorrer essas colunas e salvar aprovado para quando estiver marcado :S

Comment: Faça um laço percorrendo todas as linhas, mas restringindo apenas a coluna booleana no `getValueAt`, assim você recupera o valor dessa coluna.

Comment: vc comentou sobre o iscelleditable, mas e se eu quiser deixar apenas a coluna 22 pra ser editada?

Comment: @Lucas16 supondo que 22 seja o indice correto da coluna: `return col == 22;`

Comment: Manja demais :D

Comment: eu fiz um laço, mas estou com várias duvidas.. será q vc n poderia me ajudar em algum chat, alguma coisa?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68697/discussion-between-articuno-and-lucas16).

Comment: você teria um exemplo pra combobox na jtable agora? vc me explicou no checkbox e deu certo, mas preciso de um comobbox na jtable agora.

Comment: @Lucas16 https://stackoverflow.com/q/3256086/5524514